# Куда делаcь буква М из "грамоты"?

Tags: орфография

Как известно, слово "грамматика" пишется с удвоенной М, но при этом "грамота" и "грамотный" - в одной.
Если мне не изменяет память, тут вопрос по поводу слова "грамотный" уже обсуждался, но меня интересует несколько другое. Почему в слове "грамотный" и "грамота" исчезла одна буква М? А ведь именно это зачастую становится причиной ошибок, когда в слове "грамотный" пишут удвоенное М.

Comment: В греческом языке пишется с двумя м (мю). γράμματα (grámmata).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Наличие ММ в латинском заимствовании (грамматика) и М в греческом (грамота) зависит от фонетики и орфоэпии исходных языков. Греческое grammata усвоилось русским языком без удвоения М, т.к.  русское письмо идёт вслед за произношением. В среднегреч. языке (языке византийского периода) подобные сочетания двух согласных отражались по традиции только на письме, а произносились как один согласный звук. Поэтому русский язык лишь точно передал изменения в системе консонантизма среднегреч. языка. К тому же данное слово подверглось влиянию русских слов на -ОТ-А: охота, забота.

Грамматика заимствовано  именно из латинского, когда в кон. 16 века начали создаваться грамматики церковно-славянского языка (грамматики Зизания, Мелетия Смотрицкого и др.).
В латинском произношении комплекс из 2 гомогенных согласных сохраняется и по сей день. 
http://forum.lingvo.ru/actualthread.aspx?tid=17953

Answer (score 5):

Слова грамота/грамотный и грамматика пришли в русский язык разным путем и в разное время, хотя они оба восходят к греческому источнику gramma  - буква.

Слово "грамота" заимствовано непосредственно из греческого языка со значениями 1) "умение читать буквы" и 2) "письменный документ". В др.-рус. языке известно с 11 века, грамотей - это изначально писец, а прилагательное "грамотный" изначально относилось к документу (современное значение слово приобрело с 15 века).

Слово "граммАтика" (умение читать и писать) из греческого языка перешло в латинский, оттуда во многие языки Европы, а 17 веке попало в русский язык из польского языка. Это слово отмечается в словарях с 1704 г. с ударением грамматИка (две буквы ММ), и только впоследствии закрепилось современное произношение.

В то же время в др.-рус. языке с 11 века существовало и прямое заимствование в формах граматикИя и граматИка (одна буква М), с чем и связана изначальная постановка ударения в слове "грамматИка".

Answer (score -1):

Грамматика - сложное слово наподобие пулемету, только еще сложнее. Иногда окончание первого слова совпадает с началом следующего слова, тогда и получается сдвоенная буква. То же и с грамматикой. Язык - изобретатель этого слова, долгое время помнит технологию его изготовления и мирится с написанием двух m. А прочие языки, приняв суть этого слова, не считают обязательным соблюдать его произношение и правописание. Тем более, что, прикиньте сами, слово грамматика (с двумя m) очень неповоротливо в русском языке; то ли его производные с одним m, верти, как хочешь, и получай что хочешь. В этом заключается смысл выражения "великий и могучий"; он подомнет и переработает для себя любого "иностранца", на которого положит глаз (кроме **кофе**, пожалуй). А любознательным и дюже упорным я предложил бы раздеталировать слово грамматика (примерно, так: г(а,е)-ра-м(а,о,у)-ма-тика; в скобках указаны возможно выпавшие во временах и пространствах гласные; обычное дело)и поискать значение каждой части. Они должны быть.